# How to get frequency of sound from AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I'm implementing a speech recognition module for an app. It works fine, however there are some additional things that I need to do. For example, I need to know if a user is speaking or shouting. I know, I can achieve that by knowing the frequency of the sound. Here is how I implement it:

```
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var recognitionTask = SFSpeechRecognitionTask()

func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, _) in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        return print(error)
    }

    guard let myRecoginizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        return
    }

    if !myRecoginizer.isAvailable {
        return
    }

    recognitionTask = (speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        //Handling speech recognition tasks here
    }))!

}
```

This works fine for the speech recognition, but how can I get the frequency or amplitude value of the sound?

Comment: Have you googled it? https://medium.com/cocoondev/tpi-analysing-audio-on-ios-6fac40390125